# what's the right pattern to match my command

Tags: shell, ksh

OS: AIX 7.1
I am working on a shell script which let user input some command and execute it, one of the commands is in this form:

```
compile appname
```

the appname only can be one of [ccms|asws], what's the right pattern to match it in case statement ?

here is my shell script:

```
while true
do
 read cmd
 case $cmd in
 "compile(\s)(ccms)|(asws)") compile
  ;;
 *) break
  ;;
 esac
done

compile(){
 ...
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to understand the ksh manual for me, my english is very poor. So I just asked here, as I need to finish my job as soon as possible

Comment: So your shell is ksh? If so, please clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the `read` command to the splitting.

```
read cmd arguments
case $cmd in
  compile)
    …
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any POSIX-compliant shell:

```
case $cmd in
    "compile ccms"|"compile asws") compile
    ;;
    *) break
    ;;
esac
```